# Version conflict detected for Newtonsoft.Json. Install/reference Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 directly (Azure functions visual studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, json.net, azure-functions

I have installed the latest version of Visual Studio Enterprise 9 (15.8.06). Created an azure function (`HttpTrigger`), all worked fine and good and even published it to Azure account. I created a new function of type `blob trigger` and the problem appeared; when building the project I get the following error message. Could anyone help please?

```
//============================
Version conflict detected for Newtonsoft.Json. Install/reference 
Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 directly to project testfunction to resolve this issue. 
testfunction -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.0.0 -> 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0 -> Newtonsoft.Json (>= 11.0.2)
```

Comment: Did you try adding Newtonsoft directly like the error message says?

Comment: I tried to install the version it asked via nuget but failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure dependencies are the latest.

For a simple v2 blob trigger, packages right now are

```
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.22
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage 3.0.0
```